# React Native Android Firebase Crashlytics: Must Initialize Fabric before Using singleton()

Tags: android, reactjs, firebase, react-native, crashlytics

I have a `react native app` that already has Firebase installed on it. I am attempting to get the `Crashlytics firebase` module installed on it now.

I have gotten `iOS` to build and seems to be doing some sort of reporting to the `firebase` Dashboard as the dashboard no longer is prompting to install `crashlytics`. For `Android` I have followed these instructions: https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/crashlytics/android and have gotten the app to build but within the `react-native code` when I try to use the API (something like `firebase.crashlytics().log('hi there')` on app initialization) `iOS` proceeds as expected but `Android` throws

> "Must Initialize Fabric before Using singleton()".

I have tried getting around this with the method here: https://github.com/corymsmith/react-native-fabric/issues/82
by adding

```
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
  }
```

`/android/app/src/main/java/host/exp/exponent/MainApplication.java file`

When I try to do this the app then does not build and gives me the error:

> error: cannot find symbol class Crashlytics

at the line `(Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());)`. I'm not really sure where to proceed from here so some help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I solve the same issue by adding this on **android/app/src/main/java/com/[YourProjectName]/MainApplication.java**

```
import android.app.Application;
import com.crashlytics.android.Crashlytics;
import io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric;

public class TestApplication extends Application {
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
}
}
```